# App will not install on physical smartphone or on emulator due to socket timeout error

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-cli

I am trying to use the nativescript cli to run my app on my physical device and on an android simulation using the `tns run android` command.
When I do this i get the error below.

I've just tried adding my app files into a new 'test' app to see if that will solve the problem.

I have read a number of similar issues on github that did not match my problem and so did not provide a solution.
I have also tried running this on two different windows 10 computers.

Error shown

```
Installing on device ce04171461a2d0fc0d...
Successfully installed on device with identifier 'ce04171461a2d0fc0d'.
Unable to apply changes on device: ce04171461a2d0fc0d. Error is: Socket connection timed out..
```

My package.json file is below:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.PrototypeAssetSurveyAppDrawer",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "email-validator": "2.0.4",
    "nativescript": "^6.0.3",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.0.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^9.1.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "7.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~7.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.0"
  },
  "gitHead": "f28dbc60d74dd2cef4b645afd8fdd63bbb12c73e",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Here is my app.gradle file to allow multidex support

```
def settingsGradlePath

if(project.hasProperty("appResourcesPath")){
    settingsGradlePath = "$project.appResourcesPath/Android/settings.gradle";
} else {
    settingsGradlePath = "$rootDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/settings.gradle";
}

def settingsGradleFile = new File(settingsGradlePath);

if(settingsGradleFile.exists())
{
    apply from: settingsGradleFile;
}

android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    generatedDensities = []
    multiDexEnabled = true
  }
  dependencies {
      implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle code

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools" }
 }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0"
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1"
 }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my androidmanifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.nativescript.PrototypeAssetSurveyAppDrawer"
    android:versionCode="10000"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I expected the app to be installed correctly and for the app to then run on the device.

Comment: try reinstalling the emulator with same android image.

Comment: @Nitish I've tried using fresh virtual machines with the same result

Comment: check your plugins which require permissions from the android manifest file are added sometimes they create a socket error. also, check app name is same in your project in package.json, project folder name, and app.gradle file matches.

Comment: a new empty application has no problem working fine with hot updates. @Rakoc001

Comment: @Nitish, Did I make a mistake in copying my entire repository into a 'blank' test application? Should I have copied the code into the files individually?

How can I tell which apps need permissions in the android manifest file?

Comment: if you are doing it make sure you have installed dependencies you use and instead of copying the whole app resources folder in app folder only copy android.manifest file and plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with how I tried to implement multidex support in my app.

According to the Android instructions for multidex you need to change the "android:name" field in the "

However NativeScript does not support this change and that was causing this socket timeout problem.